# wxSocket wxWidgets failing

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Can someone provide just a simple example of how to use wxSockets write, because every time I try to use it to write to a connection I get windows coming up with this program has stopped working crap and the only thing I'm doing is using wxSocketBase::Write. Or does anyone know why it is failing?

I have even tried to hardcode the buffer that is supposed to be written with something like this:

```
wxSocketClient * sockConn = new wxSocketClient();

wxString url = "localhost";
wxIPV4address addr;
addr.Hostname(url);
addr.Service(6667);


sockConn->Connect(addr);


wxString test = wxT("testing");
    sockConn->Write(test.mb_str(), wxStrlen(test));



sockConn->Close();
delete sockConn;`
```

And every time I call write it just fails out

Also is there an easy way to get wxString to work with wxSocket, or should it be easy after I figure out what's going on here?

Right now its a lot easier to just use winsock to do all this stuff and well that's not why I have wxWidgets, I got it to make life easier.

Comment: You have not provided any information that would let us help you with your problem.  How about posting the code?

Comment: Ok well I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone provide just a simple example of how to use wxSockets write?

Yes, I can:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/socket.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  wxInitialize();
  wxSocketClient * sockConn = new wxSocketClient(wxSOCKET_WAITALL);
  wxString url = wxT("localhost");
  wxIPV4address addr;
  addr.Hostname(url);
  addr.Service(6667);
  if(!sockConn->Connect(addr, true)) {
    std::cout << "Connect failed\n";
    return 1;
  }
  wxString test = wxT("testing\n");
  sockConn->Write(test.mb_str(), wxStrlen(test));
  sockConn->Close();
  delete sockConn;
  wxUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should be using wxSocketBase.  You should use either wxSocketClient
 or wxSocketServer.  Here is a simple example of wxSocketClient

```
// connect to a server on the same machine, listening on port 3000
wxSocketClient mySocket;
wxIPV4address addr;
addr.Hostname(L"localhost");
addr.Service(3000);
mySocket.Connect(addr,true) );   // should check return for success

// write something
char sentence[100];
sprintf(sentence,"$SDDBT,%5.1f,0,0,,0*00\x13\n",depth/10.0);
mySocket.Write(sentence,strlen(sentence));
```

Looking at the code you posted, I would investigate a couple of things.

First, you should check the return from Connect() to ensure that you actually get a connection.

Second, are you using a unicode or multibyte build?  Tt looks to me like it might be unicode

Comment: Then please edit your question to describe correctly what you are doing and post your code so we can help you.  You asked for a simple example of usage, and I provided it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misusing wxString::mb_str().

The docs give us this:

> wxString::mb_str const char*
>   mb_str(wxMBConv& conv) const
>
> const wxCharBuffer mb_str(wxMBConv&
>   conv) const
>
> Returns multibyte (C string)
>   representation of the string. In
>   Unicode build, converts using conv's
>   cWC2MB method and returns
>   wxCharBuffer. In ANSI build, this
>   function is same as c_str. The macro
>   wxWX2MBbuf is defined as the correct
>   return type (without const).

This suggest to me that you should write something like

```
wxMBConv conv;
sockConn->Write(test.mb_str(conv), wxStrlen(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string test("testing");
sockConn->Write(test.c_str(), test.length);
```

Simpler to use std::string instead of wxString.